# Is it possible to host a chatbot web app made from .net botframework on Linux/Apache?

Tags: .net, apache, azure, botframework, .net-4.6

I have a chat bot made from .NET and Microsoft Bot Framework. Currently it is hosted on Azure as a web app. Is there a way to host it on a Linux/Apache server as well?

Comment: Um... If you want to host Bot service on your Linux machine, you'd better use The Bot Builder SDK for Node.js . .NET botframework should be hosted on Windows.

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT so I should take it as it is not possible for a .NET chatbot to be hosted on Linux?

Comment: I didn't test this. Just based on my knowledge, I think there is no way to achieve that for now.

Comment: .NET is a general term, do you mean .NET Core or .NET Framework 4.x?

Comment: @juvchan .NET Framework 4.6

Comment: Well, you can always try your luck with Mono - http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/runtime/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to host your current chat bot targetting **.NET Framework 4.6** on a Linux Apache web server, it is simply **impossible**.

Based on the .NET Framework supported client/server operating systems requirements, **.NET Framework 4.6** or above is only supported on **Windows based operating systems.**

Please refer to the links below for the official supported requirements as below.

- [Supported client operating systems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/get-started/system-requirements#supported-client-operating-systems)
- [Supported server operating systems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/get-started/system-requirements#supported-server-operating-systems)

Hope this helps.

Comment: In a few months it may be possible as the v4 of the framework is targeting .Net Core, but it's still in alpha version (see roadmap here: https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/wiki/Roadmap)

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution. There is an open source Chatbot framework [BotSharp](https://github.com/Oceania2018/BotSharp) which is written in C# and running on .Net Core. So it's possible run on Linux/Apache.

The github is https://github.com/Oceania2018/BotSharp.